# File Get Contents Is Converting & to html entity

Tags: php, file-get-contents

For some reason this:

```
$poster = file_get_contents('http://example.com/thing/functions/grabbers/posters.php?q=lol&name='.$name[0]);
```

Converts the & into `&amp;` im not doing any htmlentity() etc and I also tried to encode it and then decode it again but it wont do a thing. This is really bugging me im echoing it with:

```
<?= $poster; ?>
```

Comment: The content is encoded or the requesting URL?

Comment: Nothing at all is encoded, Im using no function at all that can convert it.

Comment: `Converts the & into &amp;` what is converted? `$poster` or `'http://crime.pw/torrents/functions/grabbers/posters.php?q=lol&name='.$name[0]`.

Comment: The & symbol after ?q=lol

Comment: How do you know that the `&` symbol is converted into the `&amp;`?!!

Comment: From the error_log, Also just realized i forgot to change my site address to example.com o.o

Comment: Well, then that's not a problem, that's how some special characters are saved into the log file!! To know what happened actually, you need to read on the text after `:` in the line in the error log!

Comment: @someOne you cant be more wrong its output is actually &amp;

Comment: That's **not** a matter!! what do you read after the `:` in the line in the log file?!

Comment: It reads cant be found but I found out why, Its because I used spaces in the $name so I used urlencode() and its working perfect now ty dude!